# Simple transition not working for progress bar

Tags: css

I am trying to create a simple progress bar which will show me animation in progress bar transition. I am trying it with css transition property but couldnt get the transition happening.

https://jsfiddle.net/kv7ohehg/

```css
.progress-bar_wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.progress-bar {
  background: blue;
  width: 0%;
  height: 20px;
  transition-property: width;
  transition-duration: 20s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar_wrapper">
  <div class="progress-bar" style="width:60%">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you should use css animation instead of transition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are not transitioning between "states" when the page is first loaded, but simply overwriting the width using inline style on page load. If you want the progress bar to show an animated state, use CSS animations instead:

```
.progress-bar {
  background: blue;
  height: 20px;
  animation: load 20s linear 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  width: 0%;
}

@keyframes load {
    from { width: 0%; }
    to   { width: 60%; }
}
```

A proof-of-concept example:

```css
.progress-bar_wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.progress-bar {
  background: blue;
  height: 20px;
  animation: load 20s linear 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  width: 0%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes load {
  from {
    width: 0%;
  }
  to {
    width: 60%;
  }
}

@keyframes load {
  from {
    width: 0%;
  }
  to {
    width: 60%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar_wrapper">
  <div class="progress-bar">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Alternatively, you can use a JS-based method to trigger a change in width. However, this should be considered a last-ditch effort because what you should really be doing is using CSS animations instead :) unless you also want to support browsers that do not recognise it.

```js
window.setTimeout(function() {
  document.querySelector('.progress-bar').style.width = '60%';
}, 1000);
```

```css
.progress-bar_wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.progress-bar {
  background: blue;
  width: 0%;
  height: 20px;
  transition-property: width;
  transition-duration: 20s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar_wrapper">
  <div class="progress-bar">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to remove the inline width style and toggle classes at different levels.

You could also just toggle the width.

```js
$('#btn').click(()=>{

  $(".progress-bar").toggleClass('progress-bar-70 progress-bar ');
});
```

```css
.progress-bar_wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.progress-bar {
  background: blue;
  width: 0%;
  height: 20px;
  transition-property: width;
  transition-duration: 20s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

.progress-bar-70 {
  background: blue;
  width: 70%;
  height: 20px;
  transition-property: width;
  transition-duration: 20s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress-bar_wrapper">
  <div class="progress-bar">
  </div>
</div>

<button id="btn">toggle</button>
```

Comment: You're loading an **entire** library just to toggle a class?

Comment: @Terry Its fast and easy for the sake of example. He doesnt even use Jquery in his question but also doesn't have a trigger for the animation. Why are you attacking answers from others? this is not a competition.

Comment: Stop taking criticism so personally, it's not an attack. I mean, you do not really *need* to use a library to toggle a class. What happened to using `querySelector()` and `classList.add()`? Chill out.

Comment: @Terry First I also added a button and click event, so no not just to toggle a class and its easy to check the jquery box in the editor for demonstration purposes. Its not like his machine in going to run slower from a minified jquery library and 6 lines of code. Thanks for the criticism though really taken to heart :)

Answer (score 0):

Your inline style is superseding the zero percent width you set in the CSS. You can see how changing the width from zero to some value (in this case using vanilla JavaScript), makes the transition occur:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  document.querySelector('.progress-bar').style.width = '60%';
}, 0)
```

```css
.progress-bar_wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.progress-bar {
  background: blue;
  width: 0%;
  height: 20px;
  transition-property: width;
  transition-duration: 20s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar_wrapper">
  <div class="progress-bar">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your requirement by using CSS3 animation.

```css
.wrapper{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    border:1px solid #000;
   }
   .inner_wrapper{
    float:left;
    width:0%;
    height:30px;
    background: #ff6600;
    animation-name:progress;
    animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-iteration-count:1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-name:progress;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:1;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
   }
   @keyframes progress{
    0%{
     width:0%;
    }
    100%{
     width:60%;
    }
   }
   @-webkit-keyframes progress{
    0%{
     width:0%;
    }
    100%{
     width:60%;
    }
   }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner_wrapper">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

Html:

```
  <div class="progress-bar_wrapper">
      <div class="progress-bar">

      </div>
  </div>
```

Css:

```
  .progress-bar_wrapper{
       width:100%;
        height:20px;
        background:rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
        border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  }
 .progress-bar { 
    background: blue; 
    width: 50%;  
    height: 20px; 
    webkit-transition: 20s width linear 1s;
    transition: 20s width linear 1s;
  }

  .progress-bar:hover{
     width: 0%;
   }
```

Comment: you were downvoted because you didnt understand the requirement. The progress should happen on load not on hover.